# Centering Only the Abstract Title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

Is there a way to make the title of my Abstract centered (horizontally)? I am using

```
\altchapter{\centering Abstract}
```

but it does not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}% similar to github.com/markwgirard/ucalgarythesis
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}
% to make chapter titles left aligned
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedright}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter} {20pt}{\large}

\begin{document}

\altchapter{\bf {Abstract}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: chapters are left aligned by default. Your template (where to get it) seems to do something different. That is a hint, that it really should be different.

Comment: Where can we find `ucalgthes1.cls`? Is it an altered version of [`ucalgarythesis.cls`](https://github.com/markwgirard/ucalgarythesis/blob/master/ucalgarythesis.cls)? Or something else? Please provide a link to the class.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to (https://github.com/markwgirard/ucalgarythesis)

Answer (score 2):

Switch the orientation with the switch you defined. The following example uses the class mentioned in the comments.

---

> If you do not have to use this template, do not use it. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgarythesis}
% to make chapter titles left aligned
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedright}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter} {20pt}{\large}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\justifyheading}{\centering}
\chapter{Abstract}
\renewcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedright}
\chapter{Alpaca}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for "If you do not have to use this template, do not use it."

Comment: @Mico It loads `book` and tries to pass options to the class later. What is going on there?